# Asus E200H, keyboard does not work for entering encryption password

Tags: keyboard, password, encryption, asus

For the disk encryption password, I cannot type anything and the keyboard/mouse doesn't work. I've tried the options `i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset` to no luck.

With the option `nosplash`, I see this:

```
[ xxxxxx] i8042: Can't read CTR while initializing i8042
 lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
 /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at XXXX: Input/output error
 /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at XXXX: Input/output error
 /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
 /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
 Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
 Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
Please unlock disk mmcblk0p3_crypt: _
```

If I plug in a USB keyboard that works, and once the system has booted then the keyboard works.

However before boot, I cannot use the keyboard to unlock the disk.

Comment: Hey, did you every solve this? If yes, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem and have looked this up, the only way is updating ir reflashing thd bios using the official tool given from the support site of the computers brand

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)